# Gauß's law for hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, gauss-law

Assuming that the Earth has the shape of a homogeneous hemisphere, the density of which is $\rho$ and the gravitational acceleration in the center of the flat part is g. Find the radius $R$ of this hemisphere. Universal gravitational constant is G. 
I used Gauß's law and got $\oint_{S_{1}}g dS_{1}+\oint_{S_{2}}g dS_{2}=4\pi GM$, where $S_{1}=2\pi R^{2}$ is area of the curved surface of hemisphere and $S_{2}=\pi R^{2}$ is area of the base of hemisphere. So I got $g (2\pi R^{2}+\pi R^{2})=4\pi GM=4\pi G \rho \frac{4}{6} \pi R^{3}$ so $R=\frac{9g}{8 \pi G \rho}$ however the correct answer is $R=\frac{g}{ \pi G \rho}$ and I cannot see mistake in my solution.

Comment: You assume that g is constant over the whole surface.

Comment: gauss law is used for electrostatics. Here you are thinking of Earth. Earth has no charge itself. But have huge mass, try Newton's law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use Gauss' law to solve the problem. Not that Gauss's law is not valid but the symmetry (or the lack of it) does not support the assumption that the value of g will be the same over the Gaussian you choose. You need to calculate g by integrating over the hemisphere.